# VS code settings background theme in css

Tags: visual-studio-code

I feel very wrong to ask this, but this color background bothers me a lot visually, I started studying programming recently and this happened, is there any practical solution to remove it? sorry about that.

Is there an answer to this problem ?

[image]

Comment: May be you have downloaded a color highlight extension